# Is there any better option for GUID creation than System.Guid.NewGuid() in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

In my application code i am generating GUID using `System.Guid.NewGuid()` and saving this to SQL server DB.

I have few questions regarding the GUID generation:

1. when I ran the program I did not find any problem with this in terms of performance, but I still wanted to know whether we have any other better way to generate GUID.
2. `System.Guid.NewGuid()` is this the only way to create GUID in .NET
   code?

Comment: What makes you think there is a better way?  (in fact, even in principle, why would a better way even exist?  If there were a better way, that way would be what's used as the implementation of `Guid.NewGuid`.)

Comment: you can also do it in SQL using `NEWID()`, but the way you mentioned is the way to do it in the code.

Comment: Eric Lippert posted a series on his blog about the GUID and its generation (inside and outside of .net) One point that I took away is that, using the methods they use to generate Guids its very rare to see Guid collisions. My main question would be, why do you need a better method than what is used by .Net?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/04/24/guid-guide-part-one.aspx

Comment: What do you want to improve? Should the results be a) more global, b) more unique or c) identify better ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman in my code ima using bulkcopy to insert data, before that i am gererationg GUID in .net code it self. my worry is because of random GUID insert taking much time since i am dealing with huge amount of data let us say 200 millions.

Comment: Yes, it probably is d) More Sequential. @Usr has a good answer.

Comment: Well, I can generate 200 million GUIDs using `Guid.NewGuid()` using a single core of my I5 laptop in 19.5 seconds. I doubt that `Guid.NewGuid()` is your bottleneck compared to inserting 200 million rows into a database.

Comment: And ironically, `Parallel.For(1, 200000000, (i) => Guid.NewGuid());` takes 25 seconds (6 seconds longer) and uses four cores instead of one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GUIDs generated by `Guid.NewGuid` are not sequential according to SQL Servers sort order. This means you are inserting randomly into your indexes which is a disaster for performance. It might not matter, if the write volume is small enough.

You can use SQL Servers `NEWSEQUENTIALGUID()` function to create sequential ones, or just use an int.

Comment: Why is it a disaster for performance? If everybody is inserting sequentially, every writer will contend for the last page in the table, effectively serializing all the writers.

Comment: @Gabe, this is a problem in *very* high insert situations. In this case, what you would do is insert sequentially at N places into the B-tree (N = core count or so). Never randomly, if you can help it, because it causes insane fragmentation and cache thrashing.

Comment: @urs can you suggest me the way i can generate sequential GUID in .net code it self.

Comment: This one looks good: http://developmenttips.blogspot.de/2008/03/generate-sequential-guids-for-sql.html (I have implemented such a thing myself in a similar way).

Comment: @urs in the link it is quoted that 'GUID column in SQL Server was not supposed to be sequential' do you know why?

Comment: @Pradeep, one reason is given in Gabe's comment: A few versions of SQL Serevr ago modifying the same page with multiple connections a lot lead to contention problems. Today, that problem is mostly gone until you get to very high concurrency. (Single threaded inserts are not impacted).

Answer (score 2):

One alternative way to generate guids (I presume as your PK) is to set the column in the table up like this:

```
create table MyTable(
    MyTableID uniqueidentifier not null default (newid()),
...
```

Implementing like this means that you've the choice whether or not to set them in .Net or to let SQL do it.

I wouldn't say either is going to be "better" or "quicker" though.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question:

> Is there any better option for GUID creation than
>   System.Guid.NewGuid() in .net

I would venture to say that System.Guid.NewGuid() is the preferred choice.

But for the follow up question:

> ...saving this to SQL server DB.

The answer is less clear. This has been discussed on the web for a long time. Just Google "**guid as primary key**" and you'll have hours of reading to do.

Usually when you use a Guid in Sql server it is for the reason of using as primary keys in tables. This has many nice advantages:

- It's easy to generate new values without accessing the database
- You can be reasonably sure that you locally generated Guid will NOT cause a primary key collision

But there are significant drawbacks as well:

- If the primary key is also the clustered index, inserting large amounts of new rows will cause a lot of IO (disc operations) and index updates.
- The Guid is quite large compared to the other popular alternative for a surrogate key, the int. Since all other indexes on the table contain the clustered index key, they will grow much faster if you have a Guid vs an int.
- Which will also cause more IO since those indexes will require more memory

To mitigate the IO issue, Sql Server 2005 introduced a new NEWSEQUENTIALGUID() function which can be used to generate sequential Guids when inserting new rows. But if you are ging to use that, then you will have to be in contact with the database to generate one, so you lose the possibility to generate one when off line. In this situation you could still generate a normal Guid and use that.

There are also many articles on the web about how to roll your own sequential Guids. One sample:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388157/GUIDs-as-fast-primary-keys-under-multiple-database

I have not tested any of them so I can't vouch for how good they are. I chose that specific sample because it contains some information that might be interesting. Specifically:

> It gets even more complicated, because one eccentricity of Microsoft
>   SQL Server is that it orders GUID values according to the least
>   significant six bytes (i.e. the last six bytes of the Data4 block).
>   So, if we want to create a sequential GUID for use with SQL Server, we
>   have to put the sequential portion at the end. Most other database
>   systems will want it at the beginning.

**EDIT**: Since the issue seems to be about inserting large amounts of data using bulk copy, a sequential Guid will probably be needed. If it's not necessary to know the Guid value before inserting then the answer by **Jon Egerton** would be one good way to solve the issue. If you need to know the Guid value beforehand you will either have to generate sequential Guids to use when inserting or use a workaround.

One possible workaround could be to change the table to use a seeded INT as primary key (and clustered index), and have the Guid value as a separate column with a unique index. When inserting the Guid will be supplied by you while the seeded int will be the clustered index. The rows will then be inserted sequntially, and your generated Guid can still be used as an alternative key for fetching records later. I have no idea if this is a feasible solution for you but it's at least one possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

`NewGuid` would be the generally recommended way - unless you need sequential values, in which case you can P/Invoke to the rpcrt function [UuidCreateSequential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Private Declare Function UuidCreateSequential Lib "rpcrt4.dll" (ByRef id As Guid) As Integer
```

(Sorry, nicked from VB, sure you can convert to C# or other .NET languages [as required](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/rpcrt4/UuidCreateSequential.html)).

Comment: Be careful: SQL Servers sort order might differ from this one. Need to check before using this.

Comment: @usr - we still don't know what definition the OP is using for "better", so who knows really?